# Split comma-separated input box values into array in jquery, and loop through it

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input box from which I'm retrieving the comma-separated text value (e.g. `'apple,banana,jam'`) using:

```
var searchTerms = $("#searchKeywords").val();
```

I want to split the values up into an array, and then loop through the array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: `$("searchKeywords")` <-- also, this isn't a valid selector

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
var array = $('#searchKeywords').val().split(",");
```

then

```
$.each(array,function(i){
   alert(array[i]);
});
```

OR

```
for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     alert(array[i]);
}
```

OR

```
for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
     console.log(array[index]);
}
```

Comment: Using jQuery to iterate over an array seems like overkill, and using a `for in` loop to iterate over an array (without some additional checks in the body of the loop) is incorrect. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTA7B/).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, i have removed that part. Above code shall work perfectly fine now. And you can go with simple for loop if you don't want to use jquery.

Comment: @anthony It isn't 'incorrect', just not always best practice. Your fiddle doesn't really illustrate the point clearly - the extra alerts are from the mootools library (included by jsFiddle in panel on left) which extends the JS Array prototype. A `for..in` will not enumerate the native Array properties -- see update http://jsfiddle.net/BTA7B/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = searchTerms.split(",");

for (var i in array){
     alert(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson `alert(array[i])` is correct, but the method of iteration isn't. You shouldn't be using a `for in` loop to iterate over it, otherwise you'll get considerably more alerted than you actually want (such as functions of the Array object).

Answer (score 1):

use js split() method to create an array

```
var keywords = $('#searchKeywords').val().split(",");
```

then loop through the array using jQuery.each() function. as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) says:

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time

```
$.each(keywords, function(i, keyword){
   console.log(keyword);
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation along with your answer

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21387344)

Comment: sorry guys, added some explanation