# How to remove a particular date from comma separated dates in input + jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a input like this, how do i remove particular date like 2018-01-03 from below comma separated values using jquery

```
<input type="text" id="selecteddates" value="2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-01-31">



 $('.input_fields_container').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    //user click on remove text links

           //here iam getting date value
            var removedate=$(this).attr('id');
            var newselectedDates=$('#selecteddates').val();
            //newselectedDates.replace(new RegExp(removedate + ',?'), '');


            var entryArray = newselectedDates.split(",");



            return false;
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div fieldset').remove(); x--;
        })
```

Comment: Start by splitting the value by `,`.

Comment: split it into an array (by the commas) and then find the one you want and remove it. Then combine back into a string if necessary. Did you try anything at all yet?

Comment: can you provide fiddle or code

Comment: Urgh, why do you have data like that in a  text box?

Comment: no man, iam not saving those values in db, based on that append html to div.

Comment: @user3544256 could you provide fiddle for what you have tried?

Comment: for example if date is exist iam not appending html to div, if date not exist iam appending html to div,

Comment: Doing a quick search for what people have said in comments, "Split string by comma" and "Build a string from an array" will give you everything you need. If we write it for you you'll learn nothing, you've been handed the solution, you just have to understand it and write it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757671/split-comma-separated-input-box-values-into-array-in-jquery-and-loop-through-it/11757817

please keep a habit of searching the solutions. If you don't get after a big effort then ask questions.

@AlexThomas. i've updated my answer.

Comment: Good work @Divya.

Comment: offcourse Divya, but iam tried then only iam asking, iam learning newly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if you need to remove the comma as well.

```js
var val = "2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-01-31"
var searchstring = "2018-01-03"
var startindex = val.indexOf(searchstring)
var newVal = val.substr(0, startindex) + val.substr(startindex + searchstring.length, val.length)
console.log(newVal)
```

This will be the "cleaner" solution splitting your value to an array, then using `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove the unwanted date, then joining the array back to a comma-separated string.

```js
var val = "2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-01-31".split(',') // ["2018-01-11","2018-01-03","2018-01-27","2018-01-31"]
var search = "2018-01-03"
var index = val.indexOf(search)
if (index !== -1) {
  val.splice(index, 1)
  val = val.join(',')
}
console.log(val)
```

Comment: but when i remove particular date, show double commas are in between dates.

Comment: Then use 2nd solution.